# Talend DI 8.01 - logging twarn of sub-job into the logcatcher database

Tags: logging, talend, jobs

I have a main with a sub-job (tRunJob).
Both Stats & Logs are set identically with "Use Project Setting" flag
Both use copious tWarn to monitor many key components.

The system record in the database all the activities in the main Job but none for the sub-job.

If I setup log to file in the sub-job I do get what i expected which is the activities within the sub-job but when I reset to "Use Project Setting" ie: the database, I get nothing for the sub-job.

By the way this is my first project with talend 8. For the longest time I used 6.5. So maybe there is a config parameter I'm not aware of??

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. My code loads the "context" from a config file and I forgot to reset the context of the sub-job upon entry to the one from the config so it reverted back to "default" which means my debug queries to the central log DB did not return the entries I was looking for.

what I was missing was a
contextStr = context.contextEnvironment;